# Is it possible to have variable field names?

Tags: custom-field

I am getting started with Force.com development, having worked with standard LAMP stacks in the past.

There is an issue which I seem to be running into constantly when trying to push structured data into the platform.  I have different field names that house similar data, but are all individually nuanced.

For example, some of my "account" records require a field called "Location Name" or "Location ID", while at others they need "Group" or "Division", but never both sets.

I don't want my Account pages to have all these blank boxes sitting around unused because they are applicable to some accounts, but have no relevance to others.

How have others worked around this?

Comment: Why not take this opportunity to simplify and standardize your schema?

Comment: The data structure is such that it cannot be standardized.  In a lot of cases, page templates are different for clients within different industries and provinces/states.

Answer (score 4):

addikt,

You may create different page layouts and assign them to different profiles. You may also use record types if you want to show picklist values based on different page layouts.

Comment: Record types probably would be the best option.

Comment: You can use record types to assign different layouts to the same profile - which it sounds like is exactly what Addikt wants to do.

Comment: Thank you very much for the info guys!  Very helpful!  My only question - since I'm more used to SQL and DB schema - is how do I use record types without having a table littered with NULL values?  Is this unavoidable?  If I were developing from scratch, my approach would be to establish a new table based on each template/record type.  Please see my response above to @Mike Chale regarding specifics as to answering the "why."

Comment: The nulls are unavoidable and not really an issue; I wouldn't worry about them. Trying to create new objects instead of using record types is much more burdensome and would prevent you from using lots of standard functionality.